# Retrieving items saved in a PHP session

Tags: php, session, cart

I have a PHP code to add items to a cart, which looks like follows:

```
if (is_array($_SESSION['cart']['itemId']))
        {
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['itemId']=$pid;
    $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']['qty']= $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']['qty'] + $q;
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        }
else
        {
    $_SESSION['cart']=array();
    $_SESSION['cart'][0]['itemId']=$pid;
    $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']['qty'] = $q;
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        }
```

Then I try to show the items added to the cart like this:

```
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
        {
       $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
       for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
                   {
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['itemId'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        if($q==0) continue;
    $query2 = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE id_item = :idItem");
    $query2-> bindValue (':idItem',$pid);
```

However, none of my items is loaded. Would you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session object 'cart' has different elements

See
    $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['itemId']=$pid;
    $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']['qty']= $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']['qty'] + $q;

In above two lines $max and 'itemId' are different, so you can not access them like array

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the session in the beginning of your PHP file:

```
<?php

session_start();
```

[See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: I am opening the session in each of my files, that is not the issue since I even see the number of items in the cart.

Comment: @samyb8 Do you have `error_reporting` enabled? Are you sure your SQL is working?

Comment: first do an echo $pid to make sure it's filled.

Comment: it's saying "Undefined offset 1" for this line: $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['itemId'];

Comment: What's the value of `$max`?